# Como puedo crear un array de objetos extrayendo un array que esta dentro de otro array de objetos en Javascript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, arraylist, array-bidimensional

Hola estoy tratando de crear un array nuevo basado en otro array de objetos que dentro de sus key tiene otro array de objetos. Para explicarme. Tengo la siguientes interfaces:

```
export interface  RouteElement{
  component?:  Type<any>;
  path: string;
  label: string;
  data?:{ message?: string}

}

export interface  RouterNodeElement{
  label: string;
  children: RouteElement[]
}
```

y tengo el siguiente array

```
routerNodes: [ { label: "NodeRoute", children: [ { path: 'child', label: 'child',  data: { message: 'child' }}] } ]
```

entnces basicamente tengo un array de routerNodes con el key dentro de children y lo que quiero es extraer todo los children y crear un nuevo arreglo con cada children de cada routerNodel pero no encuentro la forma de aplanar ese objeto.

trate la siguiente forma pero no funciono:

```
  const flatRouterNodes = this.routerNodes.map( route => {
    return route.children.map( child => child);
  });
```

todo lo que obtube fue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) en vez de `map`.

Como su nombre sugiere el método `flatMap` realiza un `map` de un Array y luego aplica un proceso de `flatten` sobre cada elemento del `Array` que se está iterando. En tu caso particular, tienes un Array de `routerNodes` y cada elemento de `routerNodes` tiene a su vez un Array de `children`. Tu quieres obtener todos los objetos `children` de cada uno de los `routerNode` en un solo Array (`flat`).

Por ejemplo:

```js
const routerNodes = [
  {
    label: "NodeRoute",
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child1',
        label: 'child1',
        data: { message: 'child1' }
      },
      {
        path: 'child2',
        label: 'child2',
        data: { message: 'child2' }
      }
     ]
   },
   {
    label: "NodeRoute",
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child3',
        label: 'child3',
        data: { message: 'child3' }
      }
     ]
   }
 ];
 
const childrens = routerNodes.flatMap(node => node.children);
 
console.log(childrens);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.